# Populating search input with search term

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using `SearchBar` from `react-native-elements`. How can I populate the input with the search `text` entered? I am using `redux` .

My reducer returns an array of objects. Where could I store the search term? Do I need to setup a seperate `reducer`?

```
       SearchFilterFunction(text) {
            const { filteredVideo } = this.props;
            filteredVideo(text);
        }
          <SearchBar
                    round
                    searchIcon={{ size: 24 }}
                    onChangeText={text => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
                    onClear={text => this.SearchFilterFunction("")}
                    placeholder="Type Here..."
                    value={searchTerm}
                />
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    filteredVideo: data => dispatch(filteredVideo(data))
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        videos: state.videos
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(DrawerHeader);
```

Reducer:

```
case "FILTERED_VIDEOS": {
  const newData = state.filter(function(item) {
    const itemData = item.title
      ? item.title.toUpperCase()
      : "".toUpperCase();
    const textData = action.data.toUpperCase();
    return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
  });

  return newData;
}
```

Comment: do you make use of `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: Yes, where would I store the search term value in my reducer?

Comment: this is way too less information. I'd expect `SearchFilterFunction` to set a new state for the search term value and `SearchBar` should get passed this value like so: `value={this.state.searchTerm}`